# automatic Autocomplete with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I have to accordions which contain other accordions which contain answers.

example:

```
<div id="toggles">
   <div class="acord">
      <h2>EXAMPLE</h2>
         <div class="acord">
            <h3>question 1</h3>            
            <div>    
              answer 1
            </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have a couple of questions and answers.
I have a textbox and what I want it to is to search for questions with autocomplete (jQuery).

So if I type "que" its going to show question1 question 2 etc... So if I add more questions later they should appear automatically in the list.

```
var availableTags = [];
$("#toggles h3").each(function() {
    availableTags = $(this).text(); 
 });
 
 $( ".autocomplete #input_1_1" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
  });
console.log(availableTags);
```

this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The auto complete isn't working? Can we see your input text box code?

Comment: the .autocomplete is the class of the textbox the jquery code is the code of the text box

Comment: This isn't my strong point, so forgive me if i'm off. But from coding I do know- i feel like you need to use "keyup" somewhere in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You just miss...push the text to array.....

Like this:

```js
var availableTags = [];
$("#toggles h3").each(function() {
    availableTags.push($(this).text()); 
});
 
$( ".autocomplete #input_1_1" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
console.log(availableTags);
```